# Лучший способ определить директорию своего исполняемого файла

Tags: c#

Обнаружил несколько способов раздобыть путь к исполняемому файлу программы. Но я не могу определить, какой из вариантов самый быстрый и абсолютно всегда будет выдавать путь к папке с исполняемым файлом?

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0]);
```

В программах на WPF узнал что есть ещё такой способ получения этого пути. Для WPF этот способ - самый лучший?

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location)
```

Ну и как бонусом хотелось бы узнать, какой из вариантов получения пути к рабочей папке более правильный?

```
System.Environment.CurrentDirectory;
System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

Comment: Вам надо узнать где exe файл лежит или получить рабочий каталог? Вот это `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(GetType().Assembly.Location)` вообще может выдает место. где опеределен тип, а он может и в отдельных папках лежать.

Comment: @tym32167, нужно узнать где exe файл лежит. Какой из способов самый лучший?

Comment: ну вот этот должен сработать `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location;` :)

Comment: вот этот сгодится, если ваш код запущен как то нестандартно `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)`

Comment: Остальные ваши примеры не обязательно будут указывать на exe файл.

Comment: ```var binDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).LocalPath);
```
P.s. Эта штука одинаково указывает на директорию с бинарниками, как в докере так и при обычном запуске.